# AWS Athena Timing out / not enough resources at this scale factor

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I ran into a problem with athena when I was trying to join and order two tables together. My query statement looks very similar to this:

```
SELECT * 
from Table_1 
LEFT JOIN Table_2 ON Table_1 
where Table_1.id = Table_2.id AND Table_1.date = Table_2.date 
ORDER BY Table_1.id, Table_1.date
```

My Tables are potentially big depending on the dataset I am working with, with about a million rows or more. After doing some research, I realize that the ORDER BY could potentially be slowing down my query, but even when I take it out, it is still timing out. At the same time, I need the ORDER BY to structure my data because I will be turning this into a csv file. I have also read that I could split my query up in order to use different workers and take advantage of Athena's ability to do parallel work, but I don't know exactly know how to do that in Athena, so if someone could elaborate and explain how that could possibly done, that would be perfect. Another thing that I was thinking of doing was partitioning my data based on columns, but I would like it if someone could explain the benefits to me of doing that since I won't be selecting only a portion of my table, but the whole table every time.

I don't know if this is relevant, but my file sizes are usualy around ~100mb or less. However, from the different posts on here that I see with the same problem, they are dealing with more than 10gb, so I'm not sure if there's just something wrong fundamentally with my use of Athena.

Edit: I was thinking of paginating my queries to see if that could fix my issue, such as using offset and limit in a loop and just appending the data together. Would that be a viable solution?

Comment: Are there `TEXT` columns in either table?  Can you provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each?  We _must_ know what indexes you have.

Comment: Is `id` the `PRIMARY KEY` for each table?  If so, why do you also filter on `date`?

Comment: "looks very similar" -- if not similar enough, then any advice we give will be suspect.

Comment: `OFFSET` is a _terribly inefficient way to paginate.  Instead, "remember where you left off".

Comment: `PARTITIONing` rarely provides performance.

Comment: A million rows is medium sized.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more tests on my code to see at what point it breaks in terms of the payload size, I realized that my total amount of rows were waaaaay more than it should be. I found out that my select statement is not what it actually is as I portrayed it in my post. it was missing the `AND Table_1.date = Table_2.date`  part due to a bug in the construction of query (because I am conditionally creating it). This resulted in the amount of rows being multiplied by up to 10x as I've noticed, which is what was screwing up my query and eating up all of athena's resources. So everything works fine now. However, I will leave this post up mostly for learning purposes to see if any of the questions to this potential problem are answered.